# SEO implications when using SVG for visual effects on website?

Tags: seo, design, svg

We are working on redesigning our website and want to use SVG for visual effects. Mostly header, animated icons and etc.

Are there any known issues related to SEO?

Comment: Are you trying to get the images to rank in image search, or you are you just worried about how site ranks in web search?

Comment: Web search. I know that SVG can be crawled but I have head of people having issues with duplicate title tags and such.

Comment: Icons and other template elements generally don't get scored by Google in any case. A theme with just white vs a gui heavy website with same content will rank equally as well... It is the actual page content and the actions of visitors that determine how well that site ranks.

Answer (score 5):

SEO is unconcerned with ANY animations or visual effects except if those animations and effects are the content and subject of the document. Even then, it is the textual content attached to those objects that will affect SEO, not the effects.

Comment: Use Alt tags to indicate if the image/animation is part of the content. And keep in mind a huge SEO advantage is gained with the speed of a page loading - making SVG superior to images.

Comment: What is the header SVG file is an animation about 20 seconds long with text CTA's and etc. Will that content get crawled as well?

Comment: Repeating: SEO is unconcerned with animation and effects, including its length, except when it affects the loading of a page as @Yhorian mentions. I don't know what you mean by text CTAs.